# Missing FROM-clause in RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT loop

Tags: postgresql

This query works fine, but I need to execute it for multiple tables:

```
select 'service:dms_fdo_query:joined' as metric_name, hypertable_size('prom_data."service:dms_fdo_query:joined"') as raw_size
```

I wrote this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_metric_sizes()
  RETURNS TABLE(metric_name text, raw_size bigint) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   metric_table name;
BEGIN
   FOR metric_table IN SELECT table_name FROM prom_info.metric
   loop
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT %L as metric_name, hypertable_size(prom_data.%I) as raw_size', metric_table, metric_table);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but I am getting this error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "prom_data"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function get_metric_sizes() line 7 at RETURN QUERY
```

I have really no idea how to fix this, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your dynamic SQL has no `from` clause.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but there is no “dual” table in Postgres, and the first (non dynamic) statement works fine. How do you achieve the same result with dynamic sql?

Comment: Well, you are using an identifier `prom_data` in your dynamic SQL, but it's a string constant in your regular SQL - you need to decide what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I simply needed to quote the table name passed to the function:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT %L as metric_name, hypertable_size(''prom_data.%I'') as raw_size', metric_table, metric_table);
```